# scrollTo plugin does not scroll as expected on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrolltop

i have a div that has the css option overflow:hidden. The content of the div ist larger. So i like to add two buttons to scroll the content top and down.

First i tried:

```
$('#scrollUp').click(function () { $('#qc_content').animate({scrollTop: 200},300);});
```

But the div didnt scroll. So i tried the scrollTo plugin but it wont scroll either.

Maybe someone can hava a look at my jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/vun5trf6/1/

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qc_content` is a **class** in your code, not an ID. The snippet is fixed. I have however, also removed all the libraries you were using: jQuery alone has a built-in scroll function in `animate`, triggered by simple calling `scrollTop` as the animatable property.

```js
$('#scrollDown').click(function () {
    $('.qc_content').animate({scrollTop: '+=156px'});
    /* ^ that's how you get your class */
});
$('#scrollUp').click(function () {
    $('.qc_content').animate({scrollTop: '-=156px'});
});
```

```css
div.qc_content{
  height:30px;
  width:507px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="qc_content">
<!-- ^ thats a class, not an id. -->
<div class="qc_content_wrapper"><table class="subtab_list" id="scrolllist"><tbody><tr id="r1"><td class="c3s1">A</td><td class="c3s2">2015-07-24</td><td class="c3s3">-</td></tr><tr id="r2"><td class="c3s1">B</td></tr><tr id="r3"><td class="c3s1">C</td><td class="c3s2">2015-07-24</td><td class="c3s3">-</td></tr><tr id="r4"><td class="c3s1">D</td></tr><tr id="r5"><td class="c3s1">E</td><td class="c3s2">2015-07-24</td><td class="c3s3">-</td></tr><tr id="r6"><td class="c3s1">E</td></tr><tr id="r7"><td class="c3s1">F</td><td class="c3s2">2015-07-31</td><td class="c3s3">-</td></tr><tr id="r8"><td class="c3s1">G</td></tr><tr id="r9"><td class="c3s1">H</td><td class="c3s2">2015-07-24</td><td class="c3s3">-</td></tr><tr id="r10"><td class="c3s1">I</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div>

<div class="qc_subnavigation">
  <div class="button1">
     
  </div>
  <div class="button2">
     
  </div>
  <div class="button3">
     
  </div>
  <div class="button4">
     
  </div>
  <div class="button5">
    <p id="scrollUp">ScrollUP</p>
  </div>
  <div class="button6">
    <p id="scrollDown">ScrollDown</p>
  </div>
</div>
```